# Stuffing In Multiple Bootable ISO's On The Same Pendrive

Tags: installation, boot, usb-drive, iso

I recently installed ubuntu 13.04 from a bootable 8GB usb pendrive which was created using power iso when i was on windows.Is there a way of stuffing in another bootable windows and a freebsd iso file into the same 8GB pendrive in order to set up either a dual or a triple boot pc? I'll be interested in knowing both command line tools and GUI that are available in the linux version that i'm currently running.

Comment: Bootable media inherently work in a way so that its not possible to stuff multiple **bootable** iso on one device. Maybe someone can correct me if there is.

Answer (score 1):

I googled "multiboot pendrive" and got [this](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/)

Comment: Unfortunately for me,there are no Unix's! But Excellent.

Answer (score 0):

This utility will run under Linux.

> Multisystem is an awesome tool created by LiveUSB.info, that works
>   similar to our Windows based MultiBootISOs USB creator, but was
>   created for use within Linux. It also uses Grub2 instead of Grub
>   Legacy, and can be run from within Ubuntu Linux to create a Custom
>   Multiboot UFD containing your favorite Bootable Live Linux
>   Distributions.<sup>1</sup>

To Install the Multisystem LiveUSB Tool Click [Here](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/multiboot-create-a-multiboot-usb-from-linux/)

Answer (score 0):

I used this guide when i set my usb up
http://www.pendrivelinux.com/install-grub2-on-usb-from-ubuntu-linux/
`/dev/sdc1` is my flash drive

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/USB && sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt/USB
sudo grub-install --force --no-floppy --root-directory=/mnt/USB /dev/sdc
wget pendrivelinux.com/downloads/grub.cfg -O /mnt/USB/boot/grub/grub.cfg
sudo umount /mnt/USB && sudo rmdir /mnt/USB
```

put `ubuntu.iso` in the root directory of the flash drive,
you will need to edit grub for ubuntu 13.04 on line 6 change `vmlinuz` to `vmlinuz.efi`
Here is my grub.cfg http://pastebin.com/vtMq89Z0
Here is my folder tree http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=sJUFeU7h
Here is the theme setup guide I used http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2081013
for a usb you only use steps one and two and you edit the last 2 commands to put it on your flash drive, look at my folder tree for details

Comment: I'll give this a try sometimes later and see how it goes.

Comment: you can change `/mnt/USB` to `/media/$USER/[USB's partation UUID]` then skip the 1st and 4th commands i posted, that is the default path to mount flash drive via the gui